# Objective C terminology: outlets & delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, cocoa-design-patterns, outlet

I'm having issues understanding the concept of outlets how the iPhone deals with events. Help! Delegates confuse me too. Would someone care to explain, please?

Comment: not trying to be a jerk but have you read the introductory documents at developer.apple.com?  Its just that the question would take an essay to answer.  Maybe ask a more detailed question about what is hanging you up.

Comment: The documentation that Apple provides in the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide on outlets: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW3 and delegates: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18 seems pretty thorough to me.

Comment: @Brad - I'm not a documentation person.

Comment: @BradLarson - Sorry, gotta redact that last one. It's been a while, but I've warmed up to iOS documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Outlets** (in Interface Builder) are member variables in a class where objects in the designer are assigned when they are loaded at runtime. The `IBOutlet` macro (which is an empty `#define`) signals Interface Builder to recognise it as an outlet to show in the designer.

For example, if I drag out a button, then connect it to the `aButton` outlet (defined in my interface .h file), the loading of the NIB file at runtime will assign `aButton` the pointer to that `UIButton` instantiated by the NIB.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *aButton;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;

@end
```

Then in the implementation:

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize aButton; // Generate -aButton and -setAButton: messages

-(void)viewDidAppear {
    [aButton setText:@"Do Not Push. No, seriously!"];
}

@end
```

This eliminates the need to write code to instantiate and assign the GUI objects at runtime.

---

As for **Delegates**, they are event receiving objects used by another object (usually a generalised API class such as a table view). There's nothing inherently special about them. It's more of a design pattern. The delegate class may define several of the expected messages such as:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

...and the API object calls this message on the delegate when it wants to notify it of the event. For example:

```
-(void)update:(double)time {
    if (completed) {
        [delegate process:self didComplete:totalTimeTaken];
    }
}
```

And the delegate defines the message:

```
-(void)process:(Process *)process didComplete:(double)totalTimeTaken {
    NSString *log = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Process completed in %2.2f seconds.", totalTimeTaken];
    NSLog(log);
}
```

Such use might be:

```
Process *proc = [Process new];
[proc setDelegate:taskLogger];
[proc performTask:someTask];

// Output:
// "Process completed in 21.23 seconds."
```

Comment: So delegates are actually glorified versions of what other languages like Javascript or Python interpret as callbacks, correct?

Answer (score 9):

A delegate is a object that another object can forward messages to. In other words, it's like when your mom told you to clean your room and you pawned it off on your little brother. Your little bro knows how to do the job (since you were too lazy to ever learn) and so he does it for you.

Comment: Why didn't mom ask little brother directly?