# Delegate ivar explanation

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

What exactly does this line do:

```
id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate
```

It's always declared as an instance variable in the viewcontroller that implements the delegate protocol, don't understand what it does though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that any methods or properties declared in the protocol can also be handled in the delegate. Typically setting a delegate would mean that those delegate methods are called by any instances that conform to the protocol.

A table view, for example, requires you to implement a delegate, typically on 'self'. Doing so means you inherit those properties and / or methods provided in that protocol. This is how you get those magical, `- (UITableView *)table...` methods. That's the basic idea of it.

Also, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116579/can-someone-please-explain-delegates-in-objective-c) answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

It means delegate is an object which implements `ViewControllerDelegate` protocol methods. It helps the compiler to know the methods delegate is supposed to implement.

It's useful for checking type safety at compilation time and helps with autocompletion too.